# Странные задачи в курсе по обучению

Tags: c#

С каждым разом задачки все со странностями на курсе обучения. вот кто может мне просто человеческим языком без кода объяснить такую задачу?

Задача-загадка. Задания нет — так и задумано. Не бойтесь экспериментировать. Запустите код на выполнение и внимательно изучите ошибки. Ориентируясь на текст ошибок попробуйте сами понять, что нужно сделать.

Эта задача требует смекалки и упорства!

```
static void Decode()

{

}
```

(Это подсказка которую я взял) Экспериментально из текста ошибок определите типы аргументов и тип возвращаемого значения.
Какие ошибки, откуда ошибки, что это вообще такое, от чего отталкиваться?

Comment: "Какие ошибки, откуда ошибки, что это вообще такое, от чего отталкиваться" --- написано же "**Запустите код на выполнение** и внимательно **изучите ошибки**"

Comment: для чего вообще решать такие задачи? чтобы находить ошибки или нестандартно мыслить?

Comment: первое.........никто не пишет код идеально с первого раза. всегда есть ошибки. особенно если работаешь с чужим кодом. и это способ их читать и исправлять

Comment: Очень хорошее задание, автор задания молодец. Начните с того места, где этот метод вызывается. Наверное у него должны быть аргументы и возвращаемое значение. Только не спрашивайте, откуда я знаю, я не знаю, я впервые вижу это задание.

Comment: @aepot в тексте вопроса так и написано: "(Это подсказка которую я взял) Экспериментально из текста ошибок определите типы аргументов и тип возвращаемого значения"  :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а, точняк, я еще не проснулся. Ну это действительно не просто подсказка, вот прямо указание к действию.

Comment: я уже понял что этот метод надо было просто тупо запустить в браузере курса.

Comment: просто я всякого рода задачи и задания запускаю в VS. поэтому не сразу понял.

Comment: ну теперь вызнаете, что надо читать всё внимательнее))